# @synchronized(self) block at multiple places for multiple resources in multithreaded environment , objective c

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, synchronization, locking, self

Does locking in one function from a thread, blocks all other thread trying to acquire the lock in different functions.

We can use gcd for accessing the critical sections mentioned below, just wanted to know how @synchronized(self) works.
For ex.

Do multiple threads with ONLY writeString() calls gets blocked when the execution is in  @synchronized(self){ } in writeString()?

OR
all the threads calling the functions of the same class with  @synchronized(self){} (e.g.readDataFromFile()) gets blocked when execution is in  @synchronized(self){ } in writeString() ?

```
-(void)writeString:(NSString*)string forObj:(id)obj 
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        [obj write:string];
    }
}

-(void)readDataFromFile:(NSString*)file
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        [self read];
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You don't need to copy title in the question body.

Comment: You need to show your code.   Same `self` or different `self`?

Comment: @shweta Being of the same class is irrelevant.  Is it the same *instance*?

Answer (score 1):

`@synchronized(A)` can be thought of as a lock where `A` identifies the lock to use.

If you pass the same value for `A` into two calls to `@synchronized()`, then they'll use the same lock and be exclusive.  If you pass two different values for two calls, then they will not be exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

So for this one, we need to zoom out to a bit of a larger context.

In the case where you have two instances:

```
YourClass *a = [[YourClass alloc] init];
YourClass *b = [[YourClass alloc] init];
```

`a` will sync access to both methods for itself.
`b` will sync access to both methods for itself.

So for instance, concurrently from two different threads, `a` and `b` can both run `-writeString:forObj:` at the same time without blocking.

Now if you changed the implementation to use `@synchronized(self.class)` that entirely changes the game.  Rather than syncing on the 'instance', you would be syncing on the 'class' as a whole, so every instance would have to sync access to the methods.

So for instance using the use `@synchronized(self.class)` implementation,  concurrently from two different threads, if `a` and `b` both run `-writeString:forObj:` at the same time, that would then serialize those calls so only one runs while the other is blocked waiting for the sync to unlock.

I hope that clarifies the difference between locking on an instance of a class vs locking every instance for a given class.

Edit:
May also be worth noting, if you use `@synchronized(self)` in a 'class' method like the following:

```
// implementation of 'ExampleClass'
+(void)serializeWriting:(NSString*)string toObj:(id)obj {
    @synchronized(self) {
        [obj write:string];
    }
}
```

That also changes the game, so anytime that method is called, its synced against the class itself, so something like `[ExampleClass serializeWriting:@"some string" toObj:somethingElse]` would only ever run the critical section `[obj write:string]` on a single thread no matter how many places/threads it was called from.